# Java String Manipulation : Comparing adjacent Characters in Java

Tags: java, string

i have the following problem
Given a string, return a "cleaned" string where adjacent chars that are the same have been reduced to a single char. So `"yyzzza"` yields `"yza"`.

```
stringClean("yyzzza") → "yza"      
stringClean("abbbcdd") → "abcd"       
stringClean("Hello") → "Helo"
```

Im trying my code for the input `stringClean("abbbcdd") → "abcd"`

My code is below.Im getting the partial appended string after doing the adjacent character comparison hence as of now im getting appended stringBuilder `"sb=abc"` which is not the correct output i should get the output as `"abcd"`,

```
class cleanString{

    public static String stringClean(String str){
        int startIndex = str.indexOf(str);
        char startChar = '\u0000';
        char adjacentChar = '\u0000';
        System.out.println("startIndex-->" + startIndex);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(startIndex = 0; startIndex < str.length(); startIndex += 1){
            startChar = str.charAt(startIndex);
            System.out.println("startIndex ::" + startIndex);
            System.out.println("startChar ::" + startChar);

            final int adjacentPosition = startIndex + 1;
            System.out.println("adjacentPosition ::" + adjacentPosition);
            if(adjacentPosition != str.length()){
                adjacentChar = str.charAt(adjacentPosition);
                System.out.println("adjacentChar ::" + adjacentChar);
            }
            if(startChar == adjacentChar){
                System.out.println("startChar ::" + startChar);
                System.out.println("adjacentChar::" + adjacentChar);

                System.out.println("Before Substring string --->" + str);
                str = str.substring(1);
                startIndex--;
                System.out.println("After Substring string --->" + str);
                System.out.println("IndexOf check ---->"
                    + sb.toString().indexOf(startChar));
                if(sb.toString().indexOf(startChar) != -1){
                    sb.append(adjacentChar);
                    System.out.println("Appended String in if part-->"
                        + sb.toString());
                }
            } else{
                str = str.substring(1);
                startIndex--;
                sb.append(startChar);
                System.out.println("Appended String --->" + sb.toString());
            }
        }// end of for loop
        return sb.toString();
    }

    //im getting output as abc...which is partial appended string      
    public static void main(String ...args){     
        String outputCleanString=new cleanString().stringClean("abbbcdd");      
        System.out.println("Cleaned String --->"+outputCleanString);
    }      

}
```

***Observation:***after i get the appended string "abc",and then when i move to compare the final set of characters "dd" im facing the problem in that part.

Comment: can you check whats wrong with my code,i need correction there

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, then please flag it as such.

Comment: no,Michael its not a homework question.i just saw this question in one of the websites and im solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code and the specific issue you have mentioned if the adjacent position is beyond the bounds of your string set adjacentChar to the null char as otherwise adjacentChar is seen as the last character in the string, which means that an append is not done.

```
if(adjacentPosition != str.length()){
     adjacentChar = str.charAt(adjacentPosition);
     System.out.println("adjacentChar ::" + adjacentChar);
}

else {
     adjacentChar = '/u0000';
}
```

**EDIT**

I think that the second issue you have mentioned is in this piece of code

```
 if(sb.toString().indexOf(startChar) != -1){
      sb.append(adjacentChar);
      System.out.println("Appended String in if part-->"
         + sb.toString());
 }
```

As e and o are in the buffer from Hello they are being appended when Bookkeeper is being checked. I don't think you need that line so remove it and that should fix Hello Bookkeeper.

Although Mohoamed's answer will also work.

Comment: @Belinda,it fails for one condition `stringClean("Hello Bookkeeper") → "Helo Bokeper"` could you help me out now,im getting `"Helo Bookeeper"`,The Second Part of `Bookeeper` is not getting reduced.

Comment: Remove the append if the character is already in the buffer (e, l and o will be in it from Hello) and I think that that will fix it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Belinda its not working for the string `Hello Bookkeeper` ,The second string is not getting reduced,can you check whats wrong with my code.???answer should be `Helo bokeper`, Wrong output which im getting is `Helo bookkeeper`.

Comment: sure,and highlight the edit so that i can make out the difference

Comment: no Hello is correctly being reduced to Helo,The problem lies in second part of string bookkeeper.why are you getting confused

Comment: `bookkeeper` should get reduced to `bokeper` which is NOT happening,Hope you are getting me now

Comment: I'm not. What the if statment does is append a character if it is already in the buffer. As Hello and bookeeper both contain e and o the e and o are being appended when the algorithim is checking bookkeeper.

Comment: Whilst this does fix the code posted, the original code is a poor solution to the problem. It's hard to read, difficult to debug and inefficient.

Comment: @Andy Agreed but the OP clearly wanted their code fixed rather than a different solution.

Comment: True, though I'd encourage people to solve a problem by understanding what they are trying to achieve rather than building an ever more nasty solution until it works.

Comment: @AndyT,whats wrong with my solution.could you point the pitfalls.it works for all cases now.we had to work out a solution so we approached like this

Comment: @AndyT,I think no one is perfect so we do comitt mistakes.

Comment: @Deepak - You are initialising startIndex and startChar twice, start index doesn't need to be declared outside of the loop, you are copying strings around on each iteration (very inefficient), multiple calls to length() and indexOf() are inefficient and you include three conditional blocks when you only need one.

Comment: I'm not wishing to be harsh. You need to make sure you have analysed the requirements as a whole rather than building up code to meet each condition separately.

Comment: @Andy,I will be highly thankful to you if you could reformat the code/refine the code and post it as the answer,would be helpful for future reference as well.This approach had to taken earlier since we started with it.Please could you help me

Comment: Read Peter's solution below, and consider the items I listed above. If this is homework where you were asked to fix a broken routine, I suggest you do so yourself rather than asking someone else to do it.

Answer (score 7):

If a regex based solution is acceptable you can do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1");
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/XEvsY)

Comment: can you check whats wrong with my code,i need correction there

Comment: Sometimes, the correct solution is to throw out what you have and start over from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code is overly complicated. There is absolutely no need to

```
            str = str.substring(1);
            startIndex--;
```

inside the loop - you are effectively keeping `startIndex` at 0 and chopping off characters from the beginning of the string. Instead, you should just iterate through the characters of string (and print `str.substring(startIndex)` if you want to see what's left to process).

Also, here

```
            if(sb.toString().indexOf(startChar) != -1){
                sb.append(adjacentChar);
                System.out.println("Appended String in if part-->"
                    + sb.toString());
            }
```

you aim to prevent adding the same character again if it is repeated more than twice in a row - but the code actually prevents adding a character to the builder *ever* if it is already in there, i.e. an input like "aba" will yield the incorrect output "ab".

And actually, **there is the source of your error too.** The condition is wrong:

```
            if(sb.toString().indexOf(startChar) != -1){
```

yields `true` when `startChar` *is found* in the string contained by `sb`! If you change `!=` to `==`, you will get your 'd' in the output (however, you will get an extra 'b' too).

#### Corrected algorithm

Your approach of always comparing the actual character to the next one fails when the same character is repeated more than twice in a row. The better approach is to just remember the last character appended to the buffer and skip until you find a character different from it:

```
public static String stringClean(String str){
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char lastAppendedChar = '\u0000';

    for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index += 1){
        char actualChar = str.charAt(index);

        if (actualChar != lastAppendedChar){
            sb.append(actualChar);
            lastAppendedChar = actualChar;
        }
    }// end of for loop
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you alter my code and correct it,Im struggling with this for a long time

Comment: Thanks Peter,you came to my rescue.SOS

Comment: Peter is absolutely correct, and his solution is much, much cleaner. Before I read his answer, I went off and wrote my own routine and matched his line for line. A good solution is usually the 'obvious' solution and this seems to be it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in you code is that you append the char not when new is found but when adjetance is different then curent, so always last character would not be appended.

Comment: As the last char or chars would never by appended, so ugly solution is to append to result last char. But I would change it totally, MarcoS solution seams to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String stringClean(String str) {
    if (str == null || "".equals(str)) {
        return str;
    }
    char lastChar = str.charAt(0);
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    resultBuilder.append(lastChar);
    for (int index = 1; index < str.length(); index++) {
        char next = str.charAt(index);
        if (lastChar != next) {
            resultBuilder.append(next);
            lastChar = next;
        }
    }

    return resultBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you check whats wrong with my code,i need correction there ,Please help to solve my code as well

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't restricted to use collections from `java.util` I recommend to use `Set`. See example below.

```
public static String stringClean(String input) {
    Set<Character> result = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        result.add(c);
    }

    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : result)
        sb.append(c);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
public static String stringClean(String str) {
    if (str == null || "".equals(str))
        return str;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    buffer.append(chars[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] != chars[i-1])
            buffer.append(chars[i]);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String stringClean(String str){
    int startIndex = str.indexOf(str);
    char startChar = '\u0000';
    char adjacentChar = '\u0000';
    boolean flag = false; // added
    System.out.println("startIndex-->" + startIndex);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(startIndex = 0; startIndex < str.length(); startIndex++){
        startChar = str.charAt(startIndex);
        System.out.println("startIndex ::" + startIndex);
        System.out.println("startChar ::" + startChar);

        final int adjacentPosition = startIndex + 1;
        System.out.println("adjacentPosition ::" + adjacentPosition);
        if(adjacentPosition != str.length()){
            adjacentChar = str.charAt(adjacentPosition);
            System.out.println("adjacentChar ::" + adjacentChar);
        } else {
            flag = true;
        }
        if(startChar == adjacentChar){
            System.out.println("startChar ::" + startChar);
            System.out.println("adjacentChar::" + adjacentChar);

            System.out.println("Before Substring string --->" + str);
            str = str.substring(1);
            startIndex--;
            System.out.println("After Substring string --->" + str);
            System.out.println("IndexOf check ---->"
                + sb.toString().indexOf(startChar));
            if(sb.toString().indexOf(startChar) != -1){
                sb.append(adjacentChar);
                System.out.println("Appended String in if part-->"
                    + sb.toString());
            } else if(flag) {                   /* added */
                sb.append(adjacentChar);
            }
        } else{
            str = str.substring(1);
            startIndex--;
            sb.append(startChar);
            System.out.println("Appended String --->" + sb.toString());
        }
    }// end of for loop
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this one:

```
public String stringClean(String string){
    char sc[] = string.toCharArray();

    for(int i =0;i<sc.length;i++){
        if(i!=sc.length-1){
            if(sc[i]!=(sc[i+1])){
                output+=sc[i];
            }
        }else {
            output+=sc[i];
        }
    }
    return  output;
    //System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanString(toClean){
    return toClean.replace(/(\S)\1(\1)*/g,"$1")
}
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHtk5/)

Comment: (insert slap to one's forehead here)

Comment: hey wtf, why did you add this cleanString cluggy unreadable method? the code supposed to be simple, it is for beginners; your code is appreciated but, nobody cares about writing extremely smart piece of code,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public String stringClean(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 2)return str; 

  String nextStr = str.substring(1);

  if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1)) {
    return stringClean(nextStr);
  }

  else return str.substring(0,1) +  stringClean(nextStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are solving codingbat problems, it is good,

I m a beginner too. This exercise is supposed to be just using recursion

This is my solution:

```
public String stringClean(String str) {
  if (str.length() <= 1)
      return str;

  String adj1 = str.substring(0,1);
  String adj2 = str.substring(1,2);

  String rest = str.substring(1);

  if (adj1.equals(adj2)) {
      return stringClean(rest);
  } else
      return adj1 + stringClean(rest);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hey nhathd, you should not change my solution, the question is for beginners, don't add some smart code here. i value it , but this was a wrong move!